# How do I get the number of rows selected from the query?

Tags: 8, database

In my custom module for Drupal 8, I am using the following code.

```
$query = $this->connection->select('node_field_data', 'nf_data');
$result = $query->execute();
```

I can get the number of rows looping over `$result`.

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $num++;
}
```

Is there a way to get the number of rows with a function / class method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$query = $this->connection->select('node_field_data', 'nf_data');
$result = $query->execute();
$records = $result->fetchAll();
$num_results = count($records);
```

This will leave you with `$records` being an array of all records and `$num_results` being the count of that array.

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/result-sets

Also: [Select documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21Query%21Select.php/class/Select/8.5.x) and [StatementInterface (the return val of $query->execute) documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21StatementInterface.php/interface/StatementInterface/8.5.x)

You may want to look into using [entity queries](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3AentityQuery/8.2.x), though I'm not sure what your goal is.

Answer (score 9):

`$query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField()` is faster.

```php
$number = $this->connection->select(static::TABLE_NAME, 'f')
  ->condition('event', $name)
  ->condition('identifier', $identifier)
  ->condition('timestamp', REQUEST_TIME - $window, '>')
  ->countQuery()
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better way.

Comment: This is better if you don't actually want the results, you only want the count